# passing text inside a text box to a page on click also passing multiple values

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to pass text inside `<textbox>` and update it in my sql database but I do want some text to already exist inside the `<textbox>` as you can see in the image so I am unable to pass the text inside the `textbox` to the `edit_note.php` when I click on a button or a link also I have to pass the variable `$note_id`.

**index.php**

```
$note_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `notes` WHERE `id` = $note_id AND `user_id`='$my_id'");
while ($run_note = mysql_fetch_assoc($note_query)) {
    $note_text = $run_note['text'];
    $note_date = $run_note['Note_added_dat'];
}

echo  $edit_text = "<textarea id='note'>$note_text</textarea><br><br>";
echo <a href='edit_note.php?note=$note_id&edit=$edit_text>EDIT</a>/*click this to update note*/
```

**edit_note.php**

```
if(isset($_GET['note']) && !empty($_GET['note'])) {
    $my_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
    echo  $note_id=$_GET['note'];
    echo $edit_note = $_GET['edit'];
}

if (mysql_query("UPDATE `notes` SET `text`='$edit_note',`Note_added_dat`= now() WHERE `note_id` ='$note_id' AND `user_id` = '$my_id'")) {
    {
        echo 'Note has been Edited';                
    }
}
```

**Output**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
<?php
    $note_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `notes` WHERE `id` = $note_id AND `user_id`='$my_id'");
    while ($run_note = mysql_fetch_assoc($note_query)) {
        $note_text = $run_note['text'];
        $note_date = $run_note['Note_added_dat'];
    }
?>
<form method="GET" action="edit_note.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="note" value="<?php echo $note_id;?>">
    <textarea name="edit"><?php echo $note_text;?></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Edit">
</form>
```

Comment: thanks this code really did the trick i was able to update my DB also pass both the variables 
thou would it be possible for you to explain whats going on from `<form>` to `</form>`

Answer (score 1):

```
    <?php

    $default_text = "Something";

    $note_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `notes` WHERE `id` = $note_id AND `user_id`='$my_id'");
    while ($run_note = mysql_fetch_assoc($note_query)) {
        $note_id = $run_note['id'];
        $note_text = $run_note['text'];
        $note_date = $run_note['Note_added_dat'];
    }

    if( isset($note_text) )
        echo $edit_text = "<textarea id='note'>$note_text</textarea><br><br>";
    else
        echo $edit_text = "<textarea id='note'>$default_text</textarea><br><br>";

    echo "<a href='edit_note.php?note=$note_id&edit=$edit_text>EDIT</a>"; /*click this to update note*/

    ?>


    edit_note.php
    <?php

    if(isset($_GET['note']) && !empty($_GET['note'])) {
        $my_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
        echo  $note_id=$_GET['note'];
        echo $edit_note = str_replace("\r\n", "<br>", $_GET['edit']);
    }

    if (mysql_query("UPDATE `notes` SET `text`='$edit_note',`Note_added_dat`= now() WHERE `note_id` ='$note_id' AND `user_id` = '$my_id'")) {
        {
            echo 'Note has been Edited';                
        }
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) out of the code really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!